# Add ImageView in activity File

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add ImageView to left center Horizontal inside my bodyView Method programmatically. I have tried in the following way but did not work.

```
private LinearLayout makeBodyView() {
    LinearLayout bodyView = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams bp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    //imgrightis imageview
    imgright.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_r);
    bp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.LEFT;
    imgright.setLayoutParams(bp);
    bodyView.addView(imgright);
    gridView = new SkyGridView(this);
    int cn = this.getNumColumns();
    gridView.setNumColumns(cn);
    gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(px(20));
    gridView.setVerticalSpacing(px(15));
    gridView.setPadding(px(20), px(49), px(18), px(20));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(onClick);
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(onLongClick);

    gridAdapter = new SkyGridAdapter(this);
    LayoutParams gp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    gridView.setLayoutParams(gp);
    bodyView.addView(gridView);
    bodyView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.book1);
    return bodyView;
}
```

Logcat error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adventurewalking/com.adventurewalking.activities.EpubReaderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference

Can anyone please help me??

Comment: @MikeM. I want ImageView and onclick redirect to another activity. So should i need to insert it before Layout Param ?? Can you please correct me with code. Thank you.

Comment: Guys.. Can anyone please help me !!